# I have a table in database that have id,name, createdBy, type(folder or file) parentId that is a join with id

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, recursion

```
    public void copyFolderStructure(UUID original, UUID newParent) {
        User user = userService.getCurrentUser().get();
        Document document = documentService.getById(original);
        UUID newUuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        document.setId(newUuid);
        Document newDocPar = documentService.getById(newParent);

        System.out.println(newDocPar);

        document.setParent(newDocPar);
        document.setCreatedBy(user.getLogin());
        document.setLastModifiedBy(user.getLogin());
        String directory = user.getLogin();
        String destPath = directory + File.separator + UUID.randomUUID();
        document.setPath(destPath);

        Document newDocId = documentService.save(document);

        List<Document> documents = documentService.getAllByParent(documentService.getById(original));

        for(Document doc: documents) {
            if(doc.getRecordType() == RecordType.Folder) {
                copyFolderStructure(doc.getId(),newDocId.getId());
            } else {
                doc.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
                doc.setParent(documentService.getById(newDocId.getId()));
                doc.setCreatedBy(user.getLogin());
                doc.setLastModifiedBy(user.getLogin());
                String dir = user.getLogin();
                String Path = directory + File.separator + UUID.randomUUID();
                doc.setPath(Path);
                documentService.save(doc);
            }
        }

    }
```

how i can write a recursive function with this entity in java to copy a structure with new id and parents id
I try to obtain a copy of structure for example I have a Folder1 that contains Folder2, Folder3 file1 , and Folder3 containts file2 and file3 i need to obtain a copy in db with new id and parents id for this structure or biggest
at the moment this function don't work correctly, if you know can do this non recursively

Comment: Why does it have to be recursive?

Comment: can do this and not recursively